# How to modify a proof to avoid using subtraction of natural numbers

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

$\newcommand{\eqclass}[1]{\left[#1\right]}$

Definition of equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N}^{2}= \mathbb{Z}$: for any $x, y$, $x \sim_{\mathbb{N}^{2}} y$ if and only if $x, y \in \mathbb{N}^2$ and for any $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$, if $x = \left(a, b\right)$, $y = \left(c, d\right)$, then $a + d = b + c$.

Equivalence class on $\sim_{\mathbb{N}^{2}}$: for any $x, a, b$, if $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x = \left(a, b\right)$, then for any $y$, $y \in \eqclass{x}$ if and only if $y \sim_{\mathbb{N}^2} x$.

Addition of two integers: for any $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$, if $x = \eqclass{\left(a, b\right)}$ and $y = \eqclass{\left(c, d\right)}$, then $x + y = \eqclass{\left(a + c, b + d\right)}$.

Multiplication of two integers: let $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$. If $x = \eqclass{\left(a,b\right)}$ and $y = \eqclass{\left(c, d\right)}$, then $x \cdot y = \eqclass{\left(ac + bd, ad + bc\right)}$.

Of course, $0_\mathbb{Z} = \eqclass{\left(a,a\right)}$ for any $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

I would like to prove the following lemma about integers as an [equivalent class of ordered pairs of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer): for any $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$, if $x \neq y$ and $z \neq 0$, then $x \cdot z \neq y \cdot z$. My proof goes below:

Let $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and assume that $x \neq y$ and $z \neq 0$. There are $a, b, c, d, e, f \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
x = \eqclass{\left(a, b\right)},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
y = \eqclass{\left(c, d\right)},
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
z = \eqclass{\left(e, f\right)}.
\end{equation*}
As $z \neq 0$. Then $e \neq f$. Further, as $x \neq y$, we have $a + d \neq b + c$. Further,
\begin{equation*}
x \cdot z  = \eqclass{\left(a, b\right)} \cdot \eqclass{\left(e, f\right)} = \eqclass{\left(ae + bf, af + be\right)}.
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
y \cdot z = \eqclass{\left(c, d\right)} \cdot \eqclass{\left(e, f\right)} = \eqclass{\left(ce + df, cf + de\right)}
\end{equation*}
On the one hand,
\begin{equation*}
ae + bf + cf + de = \left(a + d\right) e + \left(b + c\right) f.
\end{equation*}
On the other hand,
\begin{equation*}
af + be + ce + df = \left(a + d\right)f + \left(b + c\right)e.
\end{equation*}
Without loss of generality, we assume $f < e$. Assume that $x \cdot z = y \cdot z$. Then
\begin{equation*}
ae + bf + cf + de = af + be + ce + df.
\end{equation*}
Immediately,
\begin{equation*}
\left(a + d\right) e + \left(b + c\right) f = \left(a + d\right)f + \left(b + c\right)e.
\end{equation*}
Then we have
\begin{equation*}
\left(a + d\right)\left(e - f\right) = \left(b + c\right)\left(e - f\right).
\end{equation*}
It is clear that $a + d = b + c$, leading to contradiction. Thus, $x \cdot z \neq y \cdot z$.

In my proof, I assumed $f < e$ and used subtraction of natural numbers. Nevertheless, it seems to me that in text books, we do not define $-$ on $\mathbb{N}$, as $-$ is not closed. How to prove the lemma without definition of subtraction?

---

To prove the $\sim_{\mathbb{N}^2}$ is an equivalence relation, we need to show that $\sim$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

First of all, we show that $\sim$ is reflexive. Let $x \in \mathbb{N}^{2}$. There are $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x = \left(p, q\right)$. Obviously, $p + q = p + q$. As a result, $x \sim x$.

Next, we show that $\sim$ is symmetric. Let $x \sim y$. Then there are $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x = \left(a, b\right)$, $y = \left(c, d\right)$ and $a + d = b + c$. Obviously, $b + c = a + d$. Thus, $y \sim x$.

Finally, we show that $\sim$ is transitive. Let $x \sim y$ and $y \sim z$. By definition, there are $a, b, c, d, e, f \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x = \left(a, b\right)$, $y = \left(c, d\right)$, $z = \left(e, f\right)$ and $a + d = b + c$ and $c + f = d + e$. Assume that $a + f \neq b + e$. Clearly $a + f + c + d \neq b + e + c + d$. On the other hand, we have $a + d + c + f = b + c + d + e$, leading to contradiction. Thus, $a + f = b + e$. (I used the following lemma without proof (has to be induction if proof is needed): for any $x, y, z\in \mathbb{N}$, x + y = x + z if only if $y = z$).

As $\sim$ is reflexive, symmetric and transitive on $\mathbb{N}^{2}$, $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N}^{2}$.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by $x=[(a,b)]$. But anyway the integers are an integral domain, so if $xz=yz$ then $x=y$ or $z=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson equivalent class of $\left(a,b\right)$.

Comment: How do you get rid of the $e-f$ on each side of $(a + d)(e - f) = (b + c)(e - f)$? I think you are making use of the fact you were supposed to prove.

Comment: It might be better to state the definition of $(a,b)$ succinctly rather than relying on a link to Wikipedia.

Comment: @DavidK Got it. Will modify.

Comment: Equivalence class – under what equivalence relation? You haven't mentioned one.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what properties of the natural numbers you are permitting yourself to use. Can you use trichotomy – if $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers, then exactly one of the three statements $x<y$, $x=y$, $x>y$ is true? Are you allowed to use that if $x$, $y$, and $z\ne0$ are natural numbers, and $x<y$, then $xz<yz$? If those are allowed, then, assuming $z\ne0$, we have $x<y$ implies $xz<yz$, and $x>y$ implies $xz>yz$, so $xz=yz$ implies $x=y$.

Comment: Care to engage with my comments, Ziqi?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP does not engage with comments.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry. Busy week. Modifying.

Comment: How do you show that your "equivalence relation" is transitive, without using subtraction?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Proof added.

Answer (score 1):

*Aside:* You shouldn't use contradiction to prove transitivity. You have a direct proof sitting inside it, so use it:
If $(a,b)\sim (c,d)$ and $(c,d)\sim (e,f)$, then $a+d=b+c$ and $c+f=d+e$. From $a+d=b+c$, adding $f$
to both sides we get $a+d+f=b+c+f$. Since $c+f=d+e$, this gives $a+d+f=b+d+e$. Cancelling $d$, we get $a+f=b+e$, and this gives $(a,b)\sim(e,f)$.

You don't say whether your natural numbers include $0$ or not; mine do, but the argument below is easy to modify appropriately if yours do not.

The definition of order of natural numbers that I am aware of is:

> For natural number $n$ and $m$, $n\leq m$ if and only if there exists a natural number $h$ such that $n+h=m$.

In particular, $n\lt m$ if and only if $n\leq m$ and $n\neq m$, if and only if there exists a *nonzero* $h$ such that $n+h=m$.

So in order to avoid writing the difference, instead write that the larger number is a sum of natural numbers and use usual cancellation with natural numbers. So we are just expressing what we know in our hearts to be $e-f$ as $h$, and using that.

After
$$\left(a + d\right) e + \left(b + c\right) f = \left(a + d\right)f + \left(b + c\right)e$$
we assume that $f\lt e$, and write $e=f+h$ for some nonzero natural number $h$. Substituting we get
$$(a+d)e + (b+c)(e+h) = (a+d)(e+h) + (b+c)e$$
which gives
$$(a+d)e + (b+c)e + (b+c)h = (a+d)e + (a+d)h + (b+c)e$$
and cancelling equal summands, we obtain
$$(b+c)h = (a+d)h.$$
Since $h$ is nonzero, this would yield $b+c=a+d$, contradicting your hypothesis.

Alternatively, and better phrase, instead of writing it as a proof by contradiction, write it as a proof by contrapositive: if $z\neq 0$ and $xz=yz$, then $x=y$. The argument above shows ends with $b+c=a+d$, which gives $x=y$ as your conclusion.